# Datanode is not starting in hadoop-hbase start?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am running the following script to run all the hbase and hadoop processes in my hbase setup in virtual machine.

```
#!/bin/sh
start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh
start-hbase.sh
#hbase-daemon.sh start rest
hbase-daemon.sh start thriftr
```

Earlier all the processes used to run properly. But recently, I have force shutdown my virtual machine process without stopping the hbase and hadoop related processes. Then my datanode process stopped. Later I have formatted my name node process, using some suggestion on online. Now my name node comes properly but data node process does not come up. When I check the running java process (*JPS*) the datanode process is missing

```
4672 NodeManager
5474 ThriftServer
4098 NameNode
4408 SecondaryNameNode
5723 Jps
4555 ResourceManager
5372 HRegionServer
5246 HMaster
5182 HQuorumPeer
```

But earlier the DataNode process used to come properly. Is it because of formatting my namenode. Do I need to change any config data or someting also?

Comment: Did you check datanode log message in logs folder?

Comment: You will also need to clear out the datanode data directory if you are formatting the namenode